# How to create TableView Section Headers and Rows from Array in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have an Array with objects where i want to set Header as **hierarchy** Value But in the array **hierarchy** vale is same in two objects, Now i want to set single header for same **hierarchy** name and add all objects having same **hierarchy** name under single Section.

```
(
        {
        activity = 3465;
        code = ASWAAA;
        hierarchy = "Vodafone1 > Vodafone12 > rerer > hhkk > VIdeosocndf1";
        name = TerritoryAcc;
    },
        {
        activity = 3470;
        code = DEQWQQ;
        hierarchy = Collection;
        name = "Reverse Dependency";
    },
        {
        activity = 3489;
        code = SASWER;
        hierarchy = "Admission Form > Army School";
        name = BIOCOMM;
    },
        {
        activity = 3493;
        code = SDFREW;
        hierarchy = Collection;
        name = Rating;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dictionary grouping initializer to create dictionary with grouped objects:

```
let dic = Dictionary(grouping: array) { (element) in
    return element["hierarchy"]!
}
```

Then every dic key will be a section header name and corresponding value is the array of objects related to this section.